Remote notification in IOS
Below delegate not being triggered while receiving remote notification when iOS app is in background or quit state.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Remote message received.");
    [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}

but in foreground state below one is working
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  NSLog(@"willPresentNotification delegate triggered");
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionList | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBanner | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}


In android its working perfectly fine.
I am testing on simulater, xcode, ios 17
To handle remote messages while app is in background/quit state, do i need to go any extra miles, kindly help ?

Thanks in advancee

Do your notifications include the content-available:1 key/value?

Hi @Paulw11, this is my notification payload
{
content_available:true,
priority:'high',
data:{
title:'body',
body: 'body',
sound:'sound'
},
notification:{
title: 'title',
body:'body',
sound:'sound'
}
}

That doesn't look right https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/pushing-background-updates-to-your-app

thanks for the link, I tried this new payload
{
aps: {
"content-available"=> 1
},
acme1:'bar',
acme2:42,
notification: {
title:self.title,
body:self.body,
sound:'default'
}
}
notification being displayed but the didReceiveRemoteNotification is not triggered
